# draw borders around richtextbox

Tags: winforms

How to draw border around text inside richtextbox control?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your question is quick specific enough, could you post a mockup of what you want?

...However... typically you'll go about doing somehting like this by overriding the `OnPaint()` method of the `RichTextBox`.  There you can access the `Graphics` object being used and grab whatever `Brush` makes sense.

Also, in overriding OnPaint, make sure to call `base.OnPaint(e)` prior to performing any of your custom work--without this nothing will show, and doing it *after* your custom work might undo your work.